# How to know from controller if http.post().then... was successful?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller, angular-controller

I have a controller which uses the following line to post data to server through a factory called `SendDataFactory`:

```
SendDataFactory.sendToWebService(dataToSend)
```

And my factory `SendDataFactory` looks like this:

```
angular
  .module('az-app')
  .factory('SendDataFactory', function ($http, $q) {

    var SendData = {};

    /**
     * Sends data to server and
     */
    SendData.sendToWebService = function (dataToSend) {

      var url = "example.com/url-to-post";
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      $http.post(url, dataToSend)

        //SUCCESS: this callback will be called asynchronously when the response is available
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log("Successful: response from submitting data to server was: " + response);

          deferred.resolve({
            data: data
          });
        },

        //ERROR:  called asynchronously if an error occurs or server returns response with an error status.
        function (response) {
          console.log("Error: response from submitting data to server was: " + response);

          deferred.resolve({
            data: data
          });
        }
      );

      return deferred.promise;
    }

    return SendData;
  });
```

I have seen some examples in here and the internet with

```
$http.post().success...
```

but I want to use

```
$http.post().then...
```

since [angular documentation says](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

> The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these methods will throw $http/legacy error.

**What I need**:

Now in my controller I need to check if the `$http.post().then...` was successful or not and then do something based on success or fail. How can I achieve this?

Comment: any reason you're not using `deferred.reject`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you meant:

```
$http.post(url, dataToSend)

    //SUCCESS: this callback will be called asynchronously when the response is available
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log("Successful: response from submitting data to server was: " + response);

      deferred.resolve({
        data: response //RETURNING RESPONSE SINCE `DATA` IS NOT DEFINED
      });
    },

    //ERROR:  called asynchronously if an error occurs or server returns response with an error status.
    function (response) {
      console.log("Error: response from submitting data to server was: " + response);

      //USING THE PROMISE REJECT FUNC TO CATCH ERRORS
      deferred.reject({
        data: response //RETURNING RESPONSE SINCE `DATA` IS NOT DEFINED
      });

    }
  );

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

In your controller you now can use:

```
SendDataFactory.sendToWebService(dataToSend)
    .then(function(data) { /* do what you want */ })
    .catch(function(err) { /* do what you want with the `err` */ });
```

Comment: thank you  a lot :D this is working! Is there any way to use `.catch(function(err) { /* do what you want with the `err` */ });` to know which type of error server is returning for example a timeout or 404?

Comment: sure, you can check the `status` or `statusCode` on the response

Comment: so it would be something like: `.catch(function(err) { console.log(err.statusCode) });`  ??

Comment: Exactlly, but i suggest that you console log the err and investigate

Comment: So I tried:  `.catch(function (err){
          console.log(err.status);
        });` but nothing was printed

Comment: Try console the err itself and check inside

Comment: You saved me with catch statement. Thanks for the great answer.

Answer (score 4):

Reject the promise instead of resolving it when it is rejected by `$http`.

```
/**
 * Sends data to server and
 */
SendData.sendToWebService = function (dataToSend) {

  var url = "example.com/url-to-post";
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  $http.post(url, dataToSend)

    //SUCCESS: this callback will be called asynchronously when the response is available
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log("Successful: response from submitting data to server was: " + response);

      deferred.resolve(response.data);  // Resolving using response.data, as data was not defined.
    },

    //ERROR:  called asynchronously if an error occurs or server returns response with an error status.
    function (response) {
      console.log("Error: response from submitting data to server was: " + response);


      deferred.reject(response.data);  // Rejecting using response.data, as data was not defined.
    }
  );

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

You can then call it from your controller the same way as you handle the callback in the service using `then`.

Since `$http` returns a promise, it can be simplified further though using promise chaining. This way there is no need to use an extra deferred object.

```
/**
 * Sends data to server and
 */
SendData.sendToWebService = function (dataToSend) {

  var url = "example.com/url-to-post";

  return $http.post(url, dataToSend)

    //SUCCESS: this callback will be called asynchronously when the response is available
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log("Successful: response from submitting data to server was: " + response);

      return response.data;  // Resolving using response.data, as data was not defined.
    },

    //ERROR:  called asynchronously if an error occurs or server returns response with an error status.
    function (response) {
      console.log("Error: response from submitting data to server was: " + response);


      return $q.reject(response.data);  // Rejecting using response.data, as data was not defined.
    }
  );
}
```